# Option Value placed outside of quotes

Tags: html, wordpress, custom-post-type

While I am sure I am doing something stupid, after staring at the code for much too long, I am now stumped. I have created a select box and populate it with posts from a certain post type in Wordpress. This works fine except when viewing the source, the option value is being placed outside of the actual value attribute and all boxes are being marked as selected.

It has to be a simple mistake somewhere but if anyone can spot this, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
<label for="meta-select-providers" class="package-row-title"><?php _e( 'Provider', 'package_textdomain' )?></label>
<select name="meta-select-providers" id="meta-select-providers">

<?

    if( $providers->have_posts() )
    {
        while( $providers->have_posts() )
        {
            $providers->the_post();

            $provider_name = get_the_title();
            $provider_id = the_ID();

            ?>

            <option value="<? echo $provider_id; ?>" <?php if (isset ($package_stored_meta['meta-select-providers'])) selected( $package_stored_meta['meta-select-providers'][0], $provider_id ); ?>>
            <?php _e( $provider_name, 'package_textdomain' )?></option>

            <?
        }
    }

?>

</select>
```

*Update*

```
<option value="<? the_ID(); ?>" <?php if (isset ($package_stored_meta['meta-select-providers'])) selected( $package_stored_meta['meta-select-providers'][0], the_ID() ); ?>>
                    <?php _e( $provider_name, 'package_textdomain' )?></option>
```

Source:

```
                1647
                <option value="" selected>
                Post 1</option>

                1645
                <option value="" selected>
                Post 2</option>

                1643
                <option value="" selected>
                Post 3</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_ID()` displays (echoes) the value. From [the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID):

> Displays the numeric ID of the current post. This tag must be within The Loop.
>
> Note: This function displays the ID of the post, to return the ID use get_the_ID().

This code will work as expected:

```
<label for="meta-select-providers" class="package-row-title"><?php _e( 'Provider', 'package_textdomain' )?></label>
<select name="meta-select-providers" id="meta-select-providers">

<?

    if( $providers->have_posts() )
    {
        while( $providers->have_posts() )
        {
            $providers->the_post();

            $provider_name = get_the_title();
            $provider_id = get_the_ID();

?>

            <option value="<? echo $provider_id; ?>" <?php if (isset ($package_stored_meta['meta-select-providers'])) selected( $package_stored_meta['meta-select-providers'][0], $provider_id ); ?>>
            <?php _e( $provider_name, 'package_textdomain' )?></option>

            <?
        }
    }

?>

</select>
```

Comment: That was a stupid mistake, thank you very much. Oddly the code you posted doesn't work, where get_the_ID() is not returning a value. I placed the_ID() directly into the Option and that fixed the value problem, but now they all appear as <option value="1638" 1638 selected='selected'> so its got a double output and selected isn't working.

Comment: @BrettPowell: I forgot to add an `echo`. I've edited my answer. Let me know if it works!

Comment: That also fixed the issue with the value, thank you. Only issue is the select still doesn't work for some reason. I don't understand the selected() function that is taking 2 parameters so still stumped as to the issue there.

Comment: @BrettPowell: What's the desired result?

Comment: When the page is edited (previous results are already saved), whichever value was selected/saved previously should be the selected value in the select box.

Comment: @BrettPowell: I think it might be a problem with how you're storing the previously selected value. What does the `$package_stored_meta` array look like? I would double check to make sure `$package_stored_meta['meta-select-providers'][0]` contains the value you are expecting!

Comment: I guess the issue was actually with the original issue but I needed to go back and save each of these posts for the meta data to update. Thank you again for the help!

Comment: @BrettPowell: No problem, I'm glad you got it working!